# Advantages of Hyper Threading in software development

Tags: intel-core-i7, intel-core-i5

The Intel Core i7 has a Hyper Threading feature.

How is this feature helpful when it comes to software development? (Not game development)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hyper Threading is useful if you are using your machine for software development because current development environments are optimized to take advantage of multiple threads, which speeds up the development. Visual Studio is an example of such an environment.

However, when it comes to executing the program that you are actually coding, HT doesn't really help unless you are developing an application that takes advantage of multiple threads.

Hope I understood your question correctly.  Maybe if you can expand on why this is important to you, we can help a little more.

Comment: I am configuring my development environment at home. I get confused between two processor as I feel it almost have identical specification with only little change. Only HT is the feature that present in Core I7 but not in Core I5. Now after your answer I feel that HT is useful because If i open multiple editor Like VS , Android Emulator , Win phone 8 emulator then it is good to have

Comment: OK makes sense, yeah an i7 CPU will generally have more cache than an i5 and burst to higher rates and it could have more physical cores in addition to HT, so overall it should outperform it, but there are several generations of both and core counts, frequencies, so not quite as clear cut I guess

Comment: Some of the new Core I5 has HT enable but model that I am getting with desktop does not available with new processor.

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of simplification:

- Hyper Threading (HT) is a multiple-threads-per-core implementation
- multiple-threads-per-core implementations allow:

  - faster execution of highly threaded code, by reducing thread waits
  - make thread switches cheaper

So this feature is helpful, if you have an active thread count, that is higher than the core count. This is very often the case with server processes - e.g. a database server like MySQL will profit from HT, if (and only if) there are more queries running (not waiting for disk, but running in the strict sense of the word) than CPU cores available.

Comment: Thanks for reply. You are trying to say that If I have one system that has many software installed like SQL Server , Visual Studio Development , Android Development Envrionment then it is useful.

Comment: HT speeds up concurrent threads (same memory mapping) much more, than concurrent processes (different memory mapping), so e.g. on a single quad-core CPU, 8 processes will profit only little, but 4 processes with 2 running threads each will show performance gains.